# Why clone() doesn't work as expected?

Tags: java, clone

Having the following code in java

```
public Polynomial multiply(Polynomial aPolynomial){
    Polynomial ret = new Polynomial();
    for (Tuple i: this.pol){
        Polynomial temp = aPolynomial.clone();
        System.out.print(temp);
        for (Tuple j: temp.pol){
            j.setCoef(j.getCoef() * i.getCoef());
            j.setPower(j.getPower() + i.getPower());
        }
        ret = ret.add(temp).clone();
    }       
    return ret;
}
```

I get as output for `System.out.print(temp)`always different values. This means that `aPolynomial`get's altered somewhere during runtime.

Changing `Polynomial temp = aPolynomial.clone();` to:

```
LinkedList<Tuple> list1 = (LinkedList<Tuple>) aPolynomial.pol.clone();
Polynomial temp = new Polynomial(list1);
```

doesn't help either the output for `System.out.print(temp)` being also different on every run of the loop.

Where is my mistake?

Edit:

```
public Polynomial clone() {
    try {
        return (Polynomial)super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

printing the `hashCode()` of `temp` and `aPolynomial` does result in two different values.

`aPolynomial` does have the same `hashCode` on every run of the `for` loop.

answers to some question in the comments:

since `Polynomial`doesn't inherit from anywhere, as far as I ma concerned `super.clone()` will refer to `Object`

I do have my own `toString` method.

Comment: Does `Polynomial` class implements `clone` correctly(As if clones inside Tuple's correctly)?

Comment: "Why copy() doesn't work as expected?"... copy? I don't see copy in your code

Comment: Does it print a memory value or some other value implemented by Polynomial toString method ?

Comment: How does your `clone()` method look like? Are you also cloning your tuples (deep copy)?

Comment: @utdemir I added the implementation of clone()

Comment: Can you show examples of the outputs ?

Comment: if I print the `hashCode` for `temp` and `aPolynomial` they look different.

Comment: @giorashc it prints the values implemented by toString method.

Comment: Your `clone` uses `super.clone()`, which calls the `clone()` method of whatever `Polynomial`'s superclass is.  But you haven't told us what the superclass is.

Comment: @ajb it doesn't inherit from anywhere, so I assume it will be `Object`.

Comment: Did you implement a `toString()` method that prints out the numerical value of the `Polynomial` or is it the default implementation? If it's the default, then you should be expecting to get a different output each time since each clone should be a completely separate object.

Comment: @NemesisX00 I did implement my `toString()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is this: You verified that `temp`, the clone of `aPolynomial`, is actually a separate object. But the values you are using from that object are in the reference `temp.pol`. During the clone method, that reference is being copied over to the new `Polynomial` instance, so that both `aPolynomial` and `temp` refer to the same object with their `pol` member.

The easiest solution would be to implement a custom clone() method where you also clone the `pol` reference to the new instance of `Polynomial`.

Something along the lines of:

```
public Polynomial clone() {
    try {
        Polynomial p = (Polynomial)super.clone();
        p.pol = this.pol.clone();
        return p;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: And if `this.pol` is a `LinkedList<Tuple>` I should also provide a `clone()` method for my class `Tuple`?

Comment: Since the documentation for [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) says its `clone()` method only returns a shallow copy, yes, you would probably want to iterate over the list and clone each element individually.

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure that Java's Object#clone() does a shallow copy by default. Meaning it will create a new instance of your object (so "x.clone() != x") but the member fields will be directly copied. This means that if you have references as members the addresses will be copied and not the value. Therefore you have a clone which internally points to the same objects. When you change the state of objects in the clone it is equal to changing the state of the objects in the original.

You should do a deep copy() which will also create a new instance of your members (Tuples I guess in your case) so they don't point to the same objects. This you have to implement yourself.

That being said using clone() is regarded as **bad practice** and you shouldn't do it (why, you can Google it, especially look for Bloch's clone() vs copy constructor). Besides copy constructors (so a constructor that takes an argument of the same type as the object it constructs and uses it as a template) there are also special deep copying libraries. Or you can go with serializing your objects and copying them that way but that's only if you like the hard way.

@Edit: here's some interview where he speaks a bit about it http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html. For his full text you would need to refer to [Effective Java 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Comment: If using `clone()` is a bad practice, what other method there is to copy objects?

Comment: as I said you can for instance implement a copy constructor. There are also special libraries doing deep cloning for you. Or you can always use serialization. Using clone() will just bring pain and misery into your life.

Comment: If an inheritable type implements `clone` using a copy constructor rather than chaining via its ancestors to `object.clone()`, then any derived type must override its own `clone` member to do likewise, *even if the descendant adds no members that would require any other attention*.  By contrast, if a class and all its ancestors chain to `object.clone()`, then derived classes that add no new fields that require special attention can simply let consumers use the inherited `clone` as-is.

Comment: @supercat I see a lot of "ifs" in your statement. The truth is people get wrong clone() all the time and it brings more bad than good. Just google for a similar question. I prefer to have 3 more lines of code in my codebase than a potential, hard to find, bug.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: The claim that clone is broken and objects should use copy constructors is the *primary reason* clone is "broken" to the extent that it is.  If the documentation for `clone` had said that all legitimate cloning methods *must* chain through `super.clone()`, then it wouldn't be broken.  Implementation of `clone` via copy constructors is broken, since any class derived from one which implements `clone` via copy constructor will inherit a broken `clone` method.  The biggest defect with `clone` is that it should have been a method of a "special" `CloneableObject` class.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: If `clone` (or perhaps `internalClone`, to subclasses better control over the public `clone` interface) had been a protected member of `CloneableObject`, the compiler could reject any invocations where it wouldn't succeed.

Comment: @supercat The documentation can say what it want. The compiler has no way of making sure that each clone() chains super so people would fail to do so even if documentation would tell them to. People don't read documentations/other sources. Example is right here where it took way too long for anyone to say that it does shallow copies instead of deep ones (and even though there are a ton of similar questions). Clone is broken because it's a very special method unlike any other in Java. Also the use of Cloneable (just like) Serializeable is bad and shouldn't be encouraged just because it's there.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: By that standard, `equals` is just as broken, since the compiler can't force people to implement it correctly either.  As for deep versus shallow, that "problem" stems from Java's failure to linguistically distinguish between fields which are used to encapsulate value, identity, both, or neither.  In languages which do make the distinction (e.g. C++), templated collections can be copied without difficulty.  C++ has plenty of other problems, but preserving the value/identity distinction is one thing it did right.

Comment: @supercat equals() is a tricky method which in some cases is broken and cannot be properly implemented. But by "clone is broken" I didn't mean that it does shallow copies but that it is extra-linguistic - it creates a new object without calling the constructor. That's not good practice. Only because a language has a feature doesn't mean we should use it.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: What's perhaps needed most is a scope declaration slightly more restrictive than `protected`, which would by default only make members available to the *immediate* derived class; that class could make the member available to sub-derived classes if desired.  A protected virtual `baseClone` declared in that fashion (which, at the root level performed a memberwise clone) wouldn't be broken at all, since construction of any object would have to be done with the assistance of the base-class object, whether that assistance took the form of a chained constructor or `baseClone`.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: The only problematic aspect of `clone` from that perspective (aside from having the name which should have been left available for a public-facing member, rather than used for a `protected` one) is that it has broader scope than it should; one must thus rely upon a class' documentation to know whether `clone` should be considered as usable. BTW, in Java is there any way for a class which inherits a `protected` member to make that member inaccessible to derived classes? In .NET one can declare a dummy member with the same name to shadow the old one, but I don't know about Java.